# How to add a class to the parameters of a large class Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I've been working on this code for an hour and a half and I have still been having issues. This is my first day with JavaScript objects and I'm unsure if any of my code is best practice.

```
function Car(carModel, carManufacturer, carHorsepower, carOwner) {
    this.model = carModel;
    this.manufacturer = carManufacturer;
    this.horsepower = carHorsepower;
    this.owner = carOwner;
}

function changeCarModel(car,newModel) {
    this.model = newModel;
}

function changeCarManufacturer(car,newmanufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = newmanufacturer;
}

function changeCarHorsepower(car,newHorsepower) {
    this.horsepower = newHorsepower;
}

function changeCarOwner(car, newOwner) {
    this.owner = newOwner;
}

 function logCarInfo(car) {
     console.log(this.model);
     console.log(this.manufacturer);
     console.log(this.horsepower);
     console.log(this.owner);
}

//TODO Add an owner object!
function Owner(newName, newAddress) {
    name = newName;
    address = newAddress;
}

function changeOwnerName(owner, newName) {
    owner.name = newName;
}

function changeOwnerAddress(owner, newAddress) {
    owner.address = newAddress;
}

function main() {
    var toyota = Car('Supra', 'Toyota', '800');
    logCarInfo(toyota);
    changeCarHorsepower(toyota, '10000');
    console.log('-------');
    logCarInfo(toyota);
    changeCarHorsepower(toyota, '1000');
    console.log('-------');
    logCarInfo(toyota);
    changeCarManufacturer(toyota, 'Ford');
    console.log('-------');
    logCarInfo(toyota);
    var cooperCodes = Owner('Cooper', '1919 12th Street');
    console.log('New Owner Made');
    changeCarOwner(toyota, cooperCodes);
    logCarInfo(toyota);

}

main();
```

So I need help with this, when I attempted to add this.owner = carOwner and then add a new owner to the car object, the console.log prints undefined. I am unsure why this is happening and if you anyone knows this issue it would mean so much to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `this` in your `Owner` function

```
function Owner(newName, newAddress) {
    this.name = newName;
    this.address = newAddress;
}
```

Also, if you don't want to show `undefined`, check if the value is present before assigning

```
function Car(carModel, carManufacturer, carHorsepower, carOwner) {
    this.model = carModel ? carModel : null;
    this.manufacturer = carManufacturer ? carManufacturer : null;
    this.horsepower = carHorsepower ? carHorsepower : null;
    this.owner = carOwner ? carOwner : null;
}
```